# Syntax error using IIf

Tags: vba, excel, iif

This is a simple question I hope. I learned about IIf today and want to implement it in some cases to save a few lines.

```
IIF(isnumeric(inputs), resume next, call notnum)
```

This is in red meaning there is a syntax error, how fix this? I have scanned MSDN article on this so I am not being lazy here.

Comment: What do you mean by "isnumeric(inputs)"  - is this a function that returns a boolean?  Is it an array of booleans?

Comment: Inputs is a user input, I want to check IfNumeric on it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: IIF is used to return a result for example `msgbox "Good " & IIF(hour(now())<12,"Morning","Afternoon")` You can't use it to call routines or resume next.

Comment: just as it looks, why not simply use `If isnumeric(inputs) Then resume next Else call notnum`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how the `IIf` function works.

It's a *function*, not a *statement*: you use its return value like you would with any other function - using it for control flow is a bad idea.

At a glance, `IIf` works a little bit like the *ternary operator* does in other languages:

> ```
> string result = (foo == 0 ? "Zero" : "NonZero");
> ```

Condition, value if true, value if false, and both possible values are of the same type.

It's for turning this:

```
If foo = 0
    Debug.Print "Zero"
Else
    Debug.Print "NonZero"
End If
```

Into this:

```
Debug.Print IIf(foo = 0, "Zero", "NonZero")
```

Be careful though, `IIf` evaluates **both** the *true* and the *false* parts, so you will not want to have side-effects there. For example, calling the below `Foo` procedure:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Debug.Print IIf(IsNumeric(42), A, B)
End Sub

Private Function A() As String
    Debug.Print "in A"
    A = "A"
End Function

Private Function B() As String
    Debug.Print "in B"
    B = "B"
End Function
```

Results in this output:

```
in A
in B
A
```

That's why using `IIf` for control flow isn't ideal. But when the *true result* and *false result* arguments are *constant expressions*, if used judiciously, it can help improve your code's readability by turning `If...Else...End If` blocks into a simple function call.

Like all good things, best not abuse it.

Comment: So I can't call functions with IIf or run IsNumeric?

Comment: @ThomasShera as part of the *condition*, yes; you can build your Boolean expression off the value returned by `IsNumeric`. What will bite your in the rear at one point or another, is if either the *true part* or the *false part* has *side-effects*. In other words, the last two parameters of `IIf` should always be *constant expressions*,

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `iif` like this.

Here is a possible way to solve this:

```
if isnumeric(input) then
    do something ...
else
    call notnum
end if
```

Comment: So I can't call functions with IIf or run IsNumeric?

Comment: @ThomasShera Yes, you cannot call any other function within `iif`. If you want to call a function, you must use the classic `if`

Answer (score -1):

IIf returns a value. As Mat's Mug stated, you can use it, to hand data into another method or function, but you can't call a procedure or function, which has no return value.
IsNumeric() for the conditional is okay, though.