# Edge cases in IsNumeric- is this overthinking it

Tags: vba, excel

I have code which looks like this:

```
Select Case IsNumeric(somevariable)
    Case True
        Resume Next
    Case False
        Call notnum
    Else
        Call MyErrorHandler
End Select
```

Is this overthinking it? Is there a chance IsNumeric will return something other than True or False here or is this bad programming practice?

Comment: isnumeric will only return a boolean value. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: isnumeric never puts out an error

Comment: @DirkReichel You are right, but something like `IsNumeric(1 + ActiveSheet)` crashes.

Comment: @JohnColeman this i can not deny :D

Comment: @MatthewD thats a bit silly... having a string that can be converted to a numerical value will be true (that is ok in some way) but at the same time, a date (which is just a numerical value) will be false... the opposite would make more sense... but good to know dates do not count if they do not contain a numeric type... so they do count? they do not? i'm completely confused...

Comment: Your sample code `(1+Activesheet)` is clearly a programming error. You're basically hiding a programming error with `Resume Next`. THis kind of pattern has long been the bane of many debuggers. You should IsNumeric throw the correct error so you can debug the error.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this code is supposed to check whether a variable user enters IsNumeric, does Resume Next do something other than what it sounds like?

Comment: Resume Next is used in an error trapper, you would use something like `On error goto ErrorCheck` at the start of your code then you would have an ErrorCheck routine further down, in that routine you would have Resume Next to jump over the erroring line and continue the code after it, or you could just have Resume to retry the erroring line (I do this in one of my ADO calls because the DB I am using is a pig of a thing).

Comment: @DanDonoghue thanks man! What's simplest way to keep the code to move past this If statement? That's the keyword I mean. My error handler simply states there's an error and terminates program, I don't use Resume Next there.

Comment: I will update my answer to explain how error checking works

Comment: @ThomasShera regarding your use of `Resume Next`, is this code in an error handler, or do you mean "carry on and do stuff with the numeric input". If you aren't in an error handler `Resume Next` will throw a `Resume without error` error

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm not using my error handler. I want to do stuff with the hopefully numeric output.

Comment: @ThomasShera use of `Resume Next` is inappropriate.  See my answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It was artificial of course, but the point of the example is that it is at least possible that a call to `IsNumeric` could trigger an error so it is least conceivable that such a call might need to be embedded in an error handler.

Comment: Yes but there is no error handler there, just an error obfuscator :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP's comment *I'm not using my error handler. I want to do stuff with the hopefully numeric output*

```
Sub demo()
    Dim inputs As Variant

    inputs = InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default")

    If Not IsNumeric(inputs) Then
        notnum
    Else
        ' Do what you want with numeric input inside the Else

    End If

    ' Maybe do more stuff irrespective of input

End Sub

Sub notnum()
    ' do not numeric stuff here
End Sub
```

Or if you want to keep prompting for numeric input until the users gets it right or cancels

```
Sub demo2()
    Dim inputs As Variant

    Do
        inputs = InputBox("Enter something Numeric", "Title", "Default")

    Loop Until IsNumeric(inputs) Or inputs = vbNullString
    If Not inputs = vbNullString Then
        ' Do wht you want with numeric input inside the Else
    End If

    ' Maybe do more stuff irrespective of input

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't need the else as it will be true or false however, just a note the Else should be Case Else (moot point though as you are about to delete it)

Based on this though I wouldn't use a case for only 2 options:

```
If IsNumeric(somevariable) then
    Resume Next
Else
    Call MyErrorHandler
End if
```

Edit: Here is how error checking works:

```
Sub SheetError()
    Dim MySheet As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorCheck
    MySheet = ActiveSheet.name
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.name = MySheet
    MsgBox "I continued the code"
    ActiveSheet.name = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    MsgBox "I will never get to here in the code"
    End
ErrorCheck:
    If Err.Description = "Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic." Then
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Error I am not designed to deal with"
    End If
End Sub
```

Copy and paste this module to your personal workbook or to a new workbook and run it, step through line by line using F8 to see how it is actually dealing with the error.

Comment: so we end where we started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211344/vba-iif-syntax-error

Comment: lol, I am on both of these questions and didn't even realise it was the same person.

Comment: @DanDonoghue thank you very much, I stepped through the code, I didn't know that tidbit about renaming sheet with same name as another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Input box can have different type of input validation. Try this

```
something = Application.InputBox("Pls Insert the Number", Type:=1)
If something = False Then Exit Sub
'Type:=0 A formula
'Type:=1 A number
'Type:=2 Text (a string)
'Type:=4 A logical value (True or False)
'Type:=8 A cell reference, as a Range object
'Type:=16 An error value, such as #N/A
'Type:=64 An array of values
```